# Setting initial indent level for PHP in Emacs?

Tags: php, emacs, indentation

I typically code my PHP with one level of indentation after the initial `<?php`, but I'm having trouble finding a setting for this in Emacs with `php-mode`.

To be clear, here's what Emacs is doing:

```
<?php
echo "Hello.";

if (something)
    do_something();
```

And here's how I usually code:

```
<?php
    echo "Hello.";

    if (something)
        do_something();
```

Emacs version 23 (straight from CVS), php-mode 1.5.0.

Comment: which version of emacs and php-mode are you using?

Comment: Emacs 23 CVS (fresh build from last night), php-mode 1.5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, I think:

```
(c-set-offset 'topmost-intro 4)
(c-set-offset 'cpp-macro -4)
```

Seems to be working. `topmost-intro` sets everything, and as far as I can tell `cpp-macro` only sets the `<?php` tags.

Thanks to Cheeso for the hint which led me to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a php-mode, but in c-modes, M-x c-set-offset can help.  - it'll allow you to customize the offset for a syntactic element, and it shows you what element was used for the current line.

Comment: Almost got it by setting topmost-intro to 4, but unfortunately the indents everything over 4 spaces, including the `<?php`.

Comment: Ah - You may have to use M-x c-set-offset in different syntax elements, to get the other settings required.

Comment: Hm, is there a way to get the syntax element of the item under the point?

Comment: in cc-mode and csharp-mode and java-mode, I use M-x c-set-offset.

Comment: @Alex: anywhere in the source code typing `M-x c-set-offset` allows you to set the syntax element of item under the point. In your case, you need to change 'topmost-intro'.

Answer (score 0):

`php-mode` derives from `c-mode`, so I think all you need is:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq standard-indent 2)
(setq default-tab-width 2)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
  #'(lambda ()
    (setq c-basic-offset tab-width)))
```

If that's not what you meant, maybe you are looking for [`tab-stop-list`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabStopList)?

Comment: Nope, don't think that'll work. That just sets the tab settings, I don't see anything in there for the initial indent level. (I also ran it in Emacs and nothing has changed except for my tab widths.)